# Bind checkbox value to parent component with controlvalueaccesor

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, controlvalueaccessor

I recently started learning Angular and I'm facing a form issue. I currently have a form with a label and an input field. Since this is quite a large form I decided to make a separate component for the input and validation of the form.

A table row therefore looks like this:

```
          <tr
            app-table-row-input
            [label]="'ConfigInterval'"
            [formControl]="RestForm.controls['ConfigInterval']"
            [type]="'number'"
          ></tr>
```

HTML table-row-input

```
    <th>
    <label class="required">{{ label }}</label>
    </th>
    <th>
    <input
    type="{{ type }}"
    [ngClass]="{
      'validation invalid': !ngControl.valid
    }"
    style="width: auto"
    class="fullwidth"
    [formControl]="ngControl.control"
    required
    />
    <span
    class="validation-msg"
    *ngIf="ngControl.invalid && (ngControl.dirty || ngControl.touched)"
    >
    Not valid
    </span>
    </th>
```

The types of number and text result in the form input being updated. However when I try to also use this for the checkbox type the form isn't updated with "true" or "false" like it does when not using a separate component. My code for the checkbox currently looks like this:

html parent Form component

```
            <tr
            app-table-checkbox
            [label]="'AuthEnabled'"
            [formControl]="RestForm.controls['AuthEnabled']"
            [id]="'cb1'"
            [type]="'checkbox'"
            ></tr>
```

html checkbox input component:

```
    <th>
     <label class="required">{{ label }}</label>
    </th>
    <th>
    <input
    type="{{ type }}"
    class="fullwidth"
    id="{{ id }}"
    [formControl]="ngControl.control"
    required
    />
    <label for="{{ id }}">True or False</label>
    </th>
```

The TS in both components looks the same (except for id property not being there):

```
    export class TableCheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
   @Input() label: string;
   @Input() type = 'text';
   @Input() id: string;

   constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
   }
   writeValue(obj: any): void {}
   registerOnChange(fn: any): void {}
   registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}
   }
```

Can somebody explain why the text and number inputs do work but this doesnt work for the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type="{{ type }}"` is initially resolving as `type="text"` and only `type="checkbox"` after inputs are bound and this is messing up `ngControl.valueAccessor = this;`.

The constructor runs prior to when the inputs are bound in the component lifecycle.

Suggest removing type input from `TableCheckboxComponent` and putting `type="checkbox"` directly on the `input`.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74266112-cva?file=src/app/app-table-checkbox.component.ts)